# Splitting a string by \n but ignoring \n in quotes

Tags: c#, regex, string

I wanted to split the string using `\n` which is at end of line and ignore the `\n` which are inside quotes.

**Input:**

```
11, 12, "inside\n the\n quotes", 13, 14\n21, 22, "another \ntest\n case", 23, 24
```

**Above string should split into:**

```
11, 12, "inside the quotes", 13, 14

21, 22, "another test case", 23, 24
```

I have tried using this:

```
Regex.Split(data, "\n|^(['""].+[\n].+)");
```

But it does not ignore `\n` inside quotes.

Please guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Does `\n` on which you want to split has numbers besides it ?

Comment: Use a CSV parser. There is more than one option for .NET.

Comment: It may have numbers/character/string

Comment: [Stop creating your own CSV parsers](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble)! It's harder than you think, and there are many already working, tested, debugged parsers ready for you to drop into your project.

Comment: Is the `\n` in the input string a literal `\\` and `n`, or a linebreak?

Comment: Is there an easier, less sexy, way to predict where the newline is, like checking if it has two numbers of a certain size on either side with no spaces?  Something unsophisticated like this: \d{2}\\n\d{2}

Comment: dustmouse: There is no fixed format that there might or might not be numbers on both sides of \n.

Comment: stribizhev: \n is there in input string.

Comment: Can you use this to split on the \n outside quotes? (?<=,\s*[^"]*)\\n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for some reason you cannot use CSV parser, You can use this regex:

```
Regex.Split(data, "(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\\n");
```

This is matching `\n` only if it is outside double quotes. For regex is doing a look ahead for even number of quotes after `\n`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jH5bH3/2)

Comment: But better use CSV parser. OP's next problems without CSV parser: embedded commas (",") and embedded double quotes ("""").

Comment: Yes definitely using a CSV parser is always safest approach.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. Regex you provided works perfectly fine. Could you please also give me suggestion or provide me link, which csv parser is useful. i will try to go though that route as well.

Comment: [Check this link but I'm not a .NET person](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/built-in-net-csv-parser/)

Comment: Thanks again Anubhava. I will go though the link.

Comment: Your next problems are escaped commas `\,` and escaped quotes `\"`. Next you'll have to deal with CSV comment lines `#...`. Did you know internationalized CSV files can use semicolons `;` instead of commas? And that, if they do, they can be escaped `\;`? Remember that backslashes can be escaped too, `\\\`, and that if they are then subsequent metacharacters are not escaped. Does your regex handle all that? CSV parsers do.

Comment: `TextFieldParser` will not do the work as `TextFieldParser does not support delimiters that contain end-of-line characters.`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 string value = "11, 12, \"inside\n the\n quotes\", 13, 14\n21, 22, \"another \ntest\n case\", 23, 24";
 var values =
            Regex.Split(value, "^")
                 .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                 .SelectMany(x => Regex.Split(x, ","))
                 .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

Comment: Neil, You are splitting string using comma. I am looking to split the string using \n by ignoring \n inside quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the final working answer is a mix of the current answers.

```
 var value = "11, 12, \"inside\n the\n quotes\", 13, 14\n21, 22, \"another \ntest\n case\", 23, 24";
 var values = Regex.Split(value, @"(?s)(?=(?:(?:[^""]*?""){2})*?[^""]*?$)\n");
```

I prefer lazy matching, thus I am adding `?` quantifier wherever possible.

Output:

[image]